# Adding ActionListener to JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jformattedtextfield, sizing

[image]

The image above is six formatted textfield I initialized. I added an `ActionListener` to each one of the text fields; but after adding listener to the leftmost textfield, the text inside disappears. When I delete the listener, the text inside reappears.

[image]

I've tried to set the minimum weight, width of the columns. Any idea as to what happened here? Thanks for the help!!

The `ActionListener` I added to the textfields is as follows,

```
   formattedTextField_4.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            formattedTextField_4.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you adding this `FocusListener`? If it's inside the constructor, try it adding in the `WindowOpened` or something of the JFrame. My *assumptions* is that this focus gained is called when the text field is created.

Comment: because inside your focusgained method you are setting the text value to empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the text filed value to empty

```
formattedTextField_4.setText("");
```

Therefore every time that text field get focus nothing will be remain in text filed

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Thanks guys! But it changes without me ever focusing on it though??

Comment: your text filed may be the first component that is getting default focus. It may execute that and clear the value.

Comment: so how would I be able to not let it default to being focused?

Comment: Set focus to something else when you are creating the frame